# Renaming States and Transitions already applied to a Machine

Tags: python, transition

I'm currently dynamically creating a state machine using [tyarkoni/transitions](https://github.com/tyarkoni/transitions) for Python. However I have come to a point where I would like to rename a state and it's transitions. I'm wondering if there is a way to do this without removing and re-adding the state under a different name.

More specifically what I'm doing is I'm creating the states and transitions while doing a BF-search through a unknown system with a set of sub-systems and the actual names/IDs of the states/systems can sometimes be "discovered" at a later stage in the search than when the state was found and added to the state machine (then saved under a temporary name/id). I would then like to rename them for easier handling etc. in other parts of the program.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Example on how I thought you would be able to rename the state

```
from transitions import Machine
s = ['A','B','C'] # States
t = [['ab','A','B'],['bc','B','C'],['ca','C','A']] # Transitions
m = Machine(states=s,transitions=t,initial='A')
m.state # Current state ('A')
m.get_state('A') # Gets state 'A' (<State('A')@140486642630440>)
m.get_state('A').name # Gets state name 'A' ('A')
m.get_state('A').name = 'D' # Renames state name 'A' to 'D'
m.get_state('A') # Gets state 'A' (<State('D')@140486642630440>)
m.get_state('A').name # Gets state name 'A' ('D')
# The following generates an error, since the state isn't renamed in the machine
m.get_state('D') # (ValueError: State 'D' is not a registered state.)
```

The result as the above is executed in Python

```
>>> from transitions import Machine
>>> s = ['A','B','C'] # States
>>> t = [['ab','A','B'],['bc','B','C'],['ca','C','A']] # Transitions
>>> m = Machine(states=s,transitions=t,initial='A')
>>> m.state # Current state ('A')
'A'
>>> m.get_state('A') # Gets state 'A' (<State('A')@140486642630440>)
<State('A')@140329230661784>
>>> m.get_state('A').name # Gets state name 'A' ('A')
'A'
>>> m.get_state('A').name = 'D' # Renames state name 'A' to 'D'
>>> m.get_state('A') # Gets state 'A' (<State('D')@140486642630440>)
<State('D')@140329230661784>
>>> m.get_state('A').name # Gets state name 'A' ('D')
'D'
>>> # The following generates an error, since the state isn't renamed in the machine
>>> m.get_state('D') # (ValueError: State 'D' is not a registered state.)
ValueError: State 'D' is not a registered state.
```

This does not work as I only rename the name string, and not the actual state.
The result I want is for all references to the state `('A')` be changed to `('D')`, so for example the transitions of machine `m` would be `[['ab','D','B'],['bc','B','C'],['ca','C','D']]`

Is this possible, or do I have to stick to adding/removing the state and all it's transition references individually? If that's the case, what's a manageable way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short answer:** It's not that easy. The most stable way would be an external name mapping which you dynamically adapt.

```
names = {"A": "stateA", "B": "stateB"}
names["A"] = "stateC"
```

This could also be done in a subclass of `State` where `State.name` is reserved for the machine logic and `State.system_name` can be altered without doing harm.

If you want/need to actually replace state names. Read on.

**Longer answer:** Transitions manages states in an `OrderedDict` where keys represent the state name. Additionally, transitions are collected in events in a dictionary of lists, again with the source state name as a key. These events are bound to the model as a method named like the transition's trigger. The transitions themselves contain the attributes `source` and `dest` which contain their start and destination's .. wait for it... state names.
If auto transitions are enabled we also have `to_<state.name>` functions which are assigned to the model(s). There is even more state name related entanglement with the model including `on_enter/exit_<state.name>`. This means there are many places where strings need to be replaced.

> Where there's a will, there's a way. -- some Python coder somewhere

You can dig deep and rename everything state related but this will have some caveats. The most obvious one: if your Model class defines a `on_enter_A` you cannot just rename the method in your instance. During initialization of the state instance it has been added to the state. You can filter the methods from the `State.on_enter/exit` attributes or leave them assigned. This also means that if you rename your state from "A" to "B", it will not reassign callbacks even if a `on_enter_B` method exists in the model.

```
from transitions import Machine
from collections import OrderedDict


def rename_state(machine, old, new):
    # rename transitions
    for trigger, event in machine.events.items():
        if old in event.transitions:
            trs = event.transitions.pop(old)
            for tr in trs:
                tr.source = new
            event.transitions[new] = trs
        for trs in event.transitions.values():
            for tr in trs:
                if tr.dest == old:
                    tr.dest = new

    if "to_{0}".format(old) in machine.events:
        ev = machine.events.pop("to_{0}".format(old))
        machine.events["to_{0}".format(new)] = ev
    # rename model properties
    for mo in machine.models:
        func = getattr(mo, 'to_' + old, False)
        if func:
            setattr(mo, 'to_' + new, func)
            delattr(mo, 'to_' + old)
        if mo.state == old:
            mo.state = new
    # rename state and reconstruct ordered dict for states
    machine.states[old].name = new
    machine.states = OrderedDict((new if k == old else k, v) for k, v in machine.states.viewitems())


class Model:

    def on_exit_A(self):
        print("Exited A!")

    def on_exit_B(self):
        print("Exited B")

model = Model()
m = Machine(model, initial='A')
m.add_state("A")
m.add_state("C")
m.add_transition('go', 'A', 'C')
rename_state(m, "A", "B")
print model.state  # >>> B
model.go()  # >>> Exited A!
print model.state  # >>> C
print m.get_state('B')
```

**Are there (better) alternatives?**

You can remove transitions from the machine but states have to be filtered out the hard way in case you plan to remove and re-add states and transitions.

You could also have a list of transitions and states which you keep somewhere. In case you need to rename states, you alter the list and create a new Machine:

```
from transitions import Machine

states = ["A", "B"]
transitions = [['ab', 'A', 'B'], ['ba', 'B', 'A']]


class Model():
    pass

model = Model()

m = Machine(model, states=states, transitions=transitions, initial='A')
model.ab()
print model.state  # >>> B

# rename states and transitions
states = [s if s != "A" else "C" for s in states]
transitions = [[t, s if s != "A" else "C", d if d != "A" else "C"] for t, s, d in transitions]

m = Machine(model, states=states, transitions=transitions, initial=model.state)
model.ba()
print model.state  # >>> C
```

This however also contains risks. As mentioned earlier the machine assigns certain functions to the model. If you cannot reinitialise your model, you will have at least some broken auto transitions assigned to the model. Try calling `model.to_A()` in the second example to see what I mean.